# Saving Data to MySQL using Pomelo Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mariadb, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I applied the Migration and can see the tables in HeidiSQL but still get the error when trying to SaveChanges()

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use.'
```

LoadingInstruction.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models
{
    public class LoadingInstruction
    {
        [Key]
        public int? LoadingInstructionRecordId { get; set; }
        public string RouteId { get; set; }
        public string SalesOrderId { get; set; }       
        public int? LoadersTeamId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

LoadingInstructionContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models;

namespace NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models
{
    public class LoadingInstructionContext : DbContext
    {

        public LoadingInstructionContext(DbContextOptions<LoadingInstructionContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public LoadingInstructionContext()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<LoadingInstruction> LoadingInstruction { get; set; } = null!;


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             
            //Configuring the one to many relationship

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoadingInstruction>()
                    .HasKey(e => e.LoadingInstructionRecordId);
        }

      
         

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString), 
                   optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                     maxRetryDelay: System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                       errorNumbersToAdd: null));
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

ILoadingInstructionService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models
{
    public interface ILoadingInstructionService
    {
        Task<int> Delete(int id);
        Task<IEnumerable<LoadingInstruction>> FindAll();
        Task<LoadingInstruction> FindOne(int id);
        Task<int> Insert(LoadingInstruction loadingInstruction);
        Task<int> Update(LoadingInstruction loadingInstruction);
      
    }
}
```

MariaDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models;

namespace NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models
{
    public partial class MariaDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public MariaDbContext(DbContextOptions<MariaDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LoadingInstruction> LoadingInstruction { get; set; }

     
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=****;uid=****;pwd=****;"
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models;
using NectarWarehouseAppServer.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<MariaDbContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});




builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NectarWarehouseAppServer.Models.RouteContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoadingInstructionService, LoadingInstructionService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LoadingInstructionContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    });
});

builder.Services.AddConnections();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TodoApi v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I tried several different configurations of the connection string such as using 'user' instead of 'uid' and 'password' instead of 'pwd', leaving out the port, etc.

This is where I get the error

```
  try
            {
                await using (LoadingInstructionContext dbContext = new LoadingInstructionContext())
                {

                     foreach (var loading in loadingInstructions){
                           LoadingInstruction loadingInstruction = new LoadingInstruction();
                           loadingInstruction.RouteId = "Route1";
                           loadingInstruction.SalesOrderId = "Order1";
                           loadingInstruction.LoadersTeamId = 0;
                           dbContext.Add(loadingInstruction);
                           dbContext.SaveChanges();
                       }


                    LoadingInstruction loadingInstruction = new LoadingInstruction();
                    dbContext.Add(loadingInstruction);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you did not send the connectionstring

LoadingInstructionContext.cs:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)); /*send connectionstring with other params*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @Toxic have a nice day and coding